# Confused with arrow functions javascript

Tags: javascript, typescript

This is the code i am using to increment intVariable value using window.setinterval.

```js
var Arrow = (function () {
    function Arrow() {
        this.intVariable = 1;
        this.itemId = -1;
        this.interval = 25;
    }
    Arrow.prototype.activateTimer = function () {
        if (this.itemId === -1) {
            window.setInterval(this.showTimer(), this.interval);
        }
    };
    Arrow.prototype.showTimer = function () {
        this.intVariable += this.interval;
        console.log(this.intVariable);
    };
    return Arrow;
}());
var arrow = new Arrow();
arrow.activateTimer();
```

When I use below line the show timer function is called only once

```
window.setInterval(this.showTimer(), this.interval);
```

But when i change it to :

```
window.setInterval(() => this.showTimer(), this.interval);
```

It works perfectly.

Need some help why it worked using arrow function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should provide function to interval, not the return of the function.

Whenever you write `window.setInterval(this.showTimer(), this.interval);`
Actually you are doing this

```
var returnValue = (function () {
  this.intVariable += this.interval;
  console.log(this.intVariable); // You get your log for once
})() // -> null
window.setInterval(returnValue/*null*/, this.interval);
```

Then `setInterval` tries to call `null` after each `this.interval` and this won't give you an error on console.

But when you call it with arrow `() => this.showTimer()` this means:

```
var returnValue = function() {
  this.showTimer();
} // -> Function
window.setInterval(returnValue/*Function*/, this.interval);
```

You are providing a function to interval.

---

And also if you forget to bind your function to `this` scope you won't be able access your arrows scope. As a result you may see lots of `NaN`s

`setInterval` tries to call your registered function with global scope which is `window`. So when you write `this` in your function it will take `this` as `window`. So whenever you try to log `this.intVariable` it tries to log `window.intVariable` which is not defined.

So we should bind our function to current objects scope. So that whenever you use `this`, your scope will be binded to your current object (Arrow). And you get get your current arrows `intVariable`.

But whenever you write `() =>` you create anonymous function like above and you already connect its scope into the object. So you won't need additional binding.

Here is your solution

```
    var Arrow = (function () {
        function Arrow() {
            this.intVariable = 1;
            this.itemId = -1;
            this.interval = 25;
        }
        Arrow.prototype.showTimer = function () {
            this.intVariable += this.interval;
            console.log(this.intVariable);
        };
        Arrow.prototype.activateTimer = function () {
            if (this.itemId === -1) {
                window.setInterval(this.showTimer.bind(this), this.interval);
            }
        };
        return Arrow;

}());
var arrow = new Arrow();
arrow.activateTimer();
```

Here is a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/201daLho/)

Comment: Yup, this worked. But i am confused how i am already using this reference then what difference did bind(this) made. also if use arrow method like ()=>showtimer() then also it is working. So i need to know why these two methods are working/

Comment: @yashshukla Explained with more details, edited answer.

Comment: I have understood 70% but still confused between this, ()=> and bind(this) not exactly sure about the functionality. do you know any book or blog where i can find good info on this? Thanks a lot for your help

Comment: @yashshukla I could't find a good source for you but you may check https://developer.mozilla.org/tr/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind and https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setInterval

Answer (score 2):

You could use directly the function reference (without using parenthesis)

```
window.setInterval(this.showTimer, this.interval);
```

By using a function call,

```
window.setInterval(this.showTimer(), this.interval);
//                               ^^
```

you insert the result of the function call and not the function itself.

When you use

```
window.setInterval(() => this.showTimer(), this.interval);
```

you insert a function without actually calling it.

Comment: What's the difference in calling with and without parenthasis?

Answer (score 0):

```
window.setInterval(() => this.showTimer(), this.interval);
```

is like

`window.setInterval(function() {this.showTimer()}, this.interval);`

`window.setInterval(this.showTimer(), this.interval);` not work because you need to only pass the `this.showTimer`  but you are calling it on the fly

Comment: This gives me NAN in log

Comment: may be it is because of the code inside the showTimer if you are using this keyword inside then both act different in function and arrow function